# IE10 flexbox widths include padding, causing overflow. box-sizing: border-box doesn't fix

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

The LHS flex child in this example has 1em padding, and it will cause RHS to overflow the parent:

```
<div style="display: -ms-flexbox; box-sizing: border-box; width: 200px; border: 5px solid black">

    <div style="padding: 1em; -ms-flex-positive: 0; -ms-flex-negative: 0; -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33%; background-color: blue; box-sizing: border-box">
        LHS
    </div>

    <div style="-ms-flex-positive: 0; -ms-flex-negative: 0; -ms-flex-preferred-size: 67%; background-color: red; box-sizing: border-box">
        RHS
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GY4F4/6/

How can I eliminate the overflow when flex children have padding? `box-sizing: border-box` doesn't work.

Comment: You can actually work-around this for row flexs by just using "width" in CSS. But "height" won't work for column flexes. Here's the column version of the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GY4F4/7/

Answer (score 30):

I had similar problems with `flexbox` and `box-sizing: border-box;`. The latter one just doesn't seem to work in IE. Width wouldn't work in this case since padding will change it - but if you can use `max-width`, that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 25):

In IE `flex-basis` doesn't account for `box-sizing:border-box`. It's a know bug as described here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box

Though it has been fixed in Edge now.

Some fixes:

- Apply negative margin to its container to counteract child padding
- Use `flex-basis: calc($basisValue - $paddingValue)` **← this worked best for me**
- Use pseudo-elements instead of padding, pseudo-elements don't count as width
- Use `flex-basis: auto`
- Limit width explicitly: `max-width: $value`

Comment: Great answer, thank you! In my case `max-width` worked fine.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to solve this by adding:

```
-ms-flex-preferred-size: calc($basisValue - $paddingValue * 2);
```

So this combination worked, even when using `autoprefixer`:

```
.element {
    padding: 1rem;
    flex: 0 1 20%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: calc(20% - 2rem);
}
```

The calc value handily overrode the auto-generated prefixes, only noticed by IE.

Comment: -ms-flex-preferred-size: works well when there is padding on left and right. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The issue appears to be the value for `-ms-flex-negative: 0` on the box that has the padding, if this is set to 1, it appears to work.

The background of RHS will now remain within the box, however its content won't, although it's the same with LHS. Adding `max-width: 100%` to LHS fixes that, but not on RHS, but adding `word-break: break-all` then causes the content to break and remain within the RHS box.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iandevlin/4b7afxox/2/)

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to IE10, but in IE11, I had to explicitly set flex-basis to auto:

```
flex: 0 1 auto;
```