# flex-basis and box-sizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

According to [`flex-basis` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) the `flex-basis` property calculates the size of a flex item related to the content box, unless a different option is defined by the `box-sizing` CSS property. But I didn't get the desired result neither in current Chrome nor in IE11.

I have written 2 examples:

```css
.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
header > span {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
header > .button {
  background-color: grey;
}
header > .app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}
header#with-border-padding > span {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* this is not useful at all */
}
header#with-border-padding > .button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>

<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>
```

### [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexMM/pbkzj984/)

- **First example** is a `<header>` with 3 `<span>` tags each one having a `flex: 1 1 100%` (`flex-basis` is 100%). So every `span` is given a third part of the `header`.
- **Second example** is equal to first one, but in this case the second `span` has some border and some padding. I thought that `flex-grow` would make same result as first example but it didn't. Then I saw the [`flex-basis` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) and understood that I had to set `box-sizing: border-box;` to the flex items so that the `flex-basis` was related to the `border-box`. But it didn't either! **Anyone knows why?**

So thanks if someone can clarify about second example question.
In my code you can easily compare the sizes given to the `<span>` tags between both examples.

Answer (score 8):

So it's clear that the columns across the two rows don't line up:

[image]

```css
.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header > span {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

header > .button {
  background-color: grey;
}

header > .app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}

header#with-border-padding > span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header#with-border-padding > .button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>

<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>
```

There are several ways to tackle this problem, and they involve `flex-basis` and `box-sizing`, and also `flex-shrink` and `padding`.

For example, if you disable `flex-shrink`, the alignment problem is gone.

```css
.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header > span {
  flex: 1 0 100%; /* adjustment */
}

header > .button {
  background-color: grey;
}

header > .app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}

header#with-border-padding > span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header#with-border-padding > .button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>

<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>
```

Similarly, if you remove the padding, the alignment problem is also fixed.

```css
.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header > span {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

header > .button {
  background-color: grey;
}

header > .app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}

header#with-border-padding > span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header#with-border-padding > .button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* padding-left: 5px; */  /* adjustment */
}
```

```html
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>

<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>
```

The way `flex-basis`, `flex-shrink`, `padding` and `border-box` interact to establish box sizes involves some relatively complex calculations. They are explained here:

- [How does flex-shrink factor in padding and border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276)

A simple solution to the problem is:

```
header > span { flex: 1 0 7px; }
```

```css
.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header > span {
  flex: 1 0 7px; /* adjustment */
}

header > .button {
  background-color: grey;
}

header > .app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}

header#with-border-padding > span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header#with-border-padding > .button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>

<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
</header>
```

With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand, there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 100%. Each item will receive an equal share of free space on the line. However, `flex-basis` needs to be at least big enough to absorb the `padding` and `border` coming from `box-sizing: border-box` (in this case 7px). The columns are now aligned across rows.

Comment: This actually does not work in IE11. It still adds the padding and ignores the `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli, IE11 does appear to have rendering problems with `flex-basis` and `box-sizing`. See [here](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/3), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19316449/3597276) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21942183/3597276).